# Selenium InvalidArgumentException : cannot parse capability: browserName

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, junit, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I am using junit annotations with selenium.While running chromedriver, I am getting the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: entry 0 of 'firstMatch' is invalid
from invalid argument: cannot parse capability: browserName 
from invalid argument: must be a string
```

Below is the class:

```
static WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public static void setup(){
 
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver_114.exe");
    driver=new Chromedriver ();
    driver.get("https://my-testing-link");
}
@Test
public void login(){}
}
```

The chrome driver is getting started succesfully but it is followed by this exception. I have not used capabilities class so I am not sure what exactly is the exception. I am using selenium 3.6. I have manually added the jars(selenium-java,selenium support,selenium-chrome-driver,selenium-api) in my project. I am aware I can use Testng annotations but I was told to write tests simply using selenium and junit.

I tried updating to latest jars and adding DesiredCapabilities class but the same exception occurs. Any suggestions would be useful